# Is Lock Graphics functionality from ArcGIS 9 ArcScript available for ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, layouts, element

I have created grids and have some layout graphics and I dont want to accidentally move these elements.

I found a old script **[here](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13516)** which does what I want, and I understand that the Production Mapping extension does this but is more advanced.

I cannot recompile from ArcGIS 9 to 10 (not smart enough), but do you know if there is an finished DLL file like the one in the link but for 10.1?

I also want to know if it is possible to lock Map frame element and/or save layout settings in ArcMap 10.1

Comment: As a comment to your last line I need to point you to Bookmarks (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00660000043s000000) and Templates (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000002w000000), even if chances are you already know about this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is far from an instant solution, but there is an ArcGIS Idea to be able to [Lock Graphic Features](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000004H1x) in ArcMap that it looks like you should vote for (I just did).

If this is important to you I would advise creating an equivalent ArcGIS Idea to have this in ArcGIS Pro because I suspect it is more likely to come to fruition in that next generation product.  I will be happy to vote for that too.